# Virtual Box VM not working

Tags: release-odin, virtualbox

Hello I have a problem in Virtual Box when i try to run a vm i got this meassage

[image: This image contain the error that I got]

also Secure boot is off and virtualization is enabled

OS : Elementary OS 6

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/920689/how-to-fix-modprobe-vboxdrv-error-in-virtualbox

and my problem is fixed